# Scatter plot when x-axis is 1d Numpy array and y-axis is 2d Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to plot the relation between two sets x and y, `x` is a vector (1d Numpy array) while `y` is a 2d Numpy array, and their values are float numbers.
Each element from the vector `x` corresponds to 1d vector from `y` (to be specific the i-th element in x corresponds to the i-th column form y).

```
x=np.array([0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15])
```

and its shape is (15,)

`y` shape is (1000, 15)

And here what I have done:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, x in enumerate(x):
    ax.scatter(x,y[:,i])

plt.show()
```

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Comment: Mr_U4913 , I have tried it, but the same problem

Comment: You shouldn't use `x` as your iterator variable in your for loop. In the first iteration, you've overwritten your original `x` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scatter plot places points that each have 1 x- and 1 y-value.
You just tried to plot points that that have 1 x- and 1000 y-values.
Of course python doesn't know what to do with that. You can try to fill out the necessary x values. Also try to avoid double usage of x:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, val in enumerate(x):
    ax.scatter([val]*1000,y[:,i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I have tried something closed to this approach, firstly I transpose my (y), then I flatten() it , also for x I repeated its values, each one 1000 times: m = 0.01
x=[None]*15000
for i in range (15000):
  n = (i+1) // 1000
  x[i]= m+ m*n , then I plot them (they become with same size), but the plot appear as I have not expected

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to plot

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see it works now, I was trying to describe the effect of the mean of a feature on its t-test value, then the effect on feature selection stability.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y[0,:])
plt.show()
```